# Почему футер прилип к верхушке?

Tags: вёрстка, css

вот у меня есть такой CSS:

```
#header{
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
}

#footer{
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

#container{
    margin: auto;
    border: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Далее HTML код:

```
<html>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
<?php
include("block/header.php");
?>
<b><font color= "white">Привет</font></b>
</div>
<div id="left">
<?include("block/left.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<?include("block/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Но почему-то не работает :( Вот как выглядит мой сайт

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй footer'у добавить свойство "clear: both"

Comment: Отлично всё сработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #footer{clear:both;}
```

Очистка потока.

Есть разные способа очистки потока которые просто необходимо знать!!
[Clearfix - очищение потока с сохранением структурной верстки](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/clearfix.html).

Comment: Спасибо всё работает как надо !)

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема возникла потому что Вы применили `float: left;` В данном случае, чтобы исправить ситуацию либо уберите `float` и задайте `width` (фиксированную ширину) либо как посоветовал [[@nMike](/users/2650/nmike)](/users/2650/nmike) добавьте в футер `clear: both;`